# numpy.loadtxt "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, numpy, alignment, sequence

A minimal example that reproduces this is:

```
import numpy
numpy.loadtxt("data.txt", delimiter='\t')
```

with `data.txt` being:

```
    A   R   N   D   C   Q
A   5   -2  -1  -2  -1  -1
R   -2  7   -1  -2  -4  1
N   -1  -1  7   2   -2  0
```

When running the code I get a ValueError:

```
[root@mycomp]$ python Needleman-Wunsch.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Needleman-Wunsch.py", line 92, in <module>
        (alignedSeq1, alignedSeq2) = computeFMatrix(seq1, seq2, -6)
    File "Needleman-Wunsch.py", line 34, in computeFMatrix
        similarityMatrixMap = readBLOSUM50("BLOSUM50.txt")
    File "Needleman-Wunsch.py", line 16, in readBLOSUM50
        similarityMatrix = np.loadtxt(fileName, delimiter='\t')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 827, in loadtxt
        items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]    
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: A  R  N  D  C  Q  E  G  H  I  L  K  M  F  P  S  T  W  Y  V
```

You can also have [the original `BLOSUM50.txt` file](https://code.google.com/p/compscimed/source/browse/alignment/blosum50.txt) and the full code is from [the link above](http://www.codesofmylife.com/2011/04/10/needleman-wunsch-algorithm-for-global-sequence-alignment-in-python/).

Erasing the first line of `BLOSUM50.txt` gave the same error.

Comment: I radically simplified your question. If I did something wrong, feel free to shout at me. (Worst comes to worst there is a "revert" button.) This makes your problem *much* more simply stated, though, so it's probably best you keep the changes IMHO.

Comment: Where did you get the original `BLOSUM50` file? It's not what the code expects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just replace the `loadtxt` with

```
numpy.genfromtxt("data.txt", delimiter='\t', skip_header=True)[:, 1:]
```

This skips the header, converts the column names to `nan` and then chops them off.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are reading the non-numeric values from the file.
You need to specify the columns you want to use and the rows you want to skip:

```
similarityMatrix = np.loadtxt('blosum50.txt', skiprows=1, delimiter='\t', usecols=range(1,num_cols+1))
```

This worked for me with your previous posted code. :D

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but the variable 'num_cols' is not defined. Is it supposed to be the number of columns in the data file, which is 20? But, when I change it to 20, it gets IndexError.

Comment: It should be 21, as the second parameter is exclusive.

Comment: Actually for your previous code the replaced line goes like
    similarityMatrix = np.loadtxt(fileName, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,len(t)+1))